Can I decompose a matrix $M \in \{ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \; | \; PA + A^TP = 0 \}$ for $P = P^T$ into $M = JP$ with $J^T = -J$?
I am currently looking at the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} =  \{ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \; | \; PA + A^TP = 0 \}$ for $P = P^T$. It is clear that the matrix $JP$ where $J^T = -J$ always lies in $\mathfrak{g}$ because $PJP + (JP)^TP = PJP - PJP = 0$ holds. I wonder if this allows me to find an skew-symmetric matrix $J$ for every matrix, let's call it $M \in \mathfrak{g}$, so that $M$ can be decomposed into $M = JP$. If so, where can I find literature about this?

If we assume that $P$ is invertible the statement is true. Given $M$ let us define $B$ via
$$ B = M P^{-1}\,.$$
The condition that $M$ is an element of the algebra then demands that
$$ 0 =  PB P + P B^T P = P(B+B^T)P\,. $$
As $P$ is invertible it follows that $B$ is skew-symmetric with $B^T = -B$.
If $P$ is not invertible, the result does not follow as you can check for $P=0$ where all matrices are in $g$.

For the sake of completeness: We know that $M = MP^{-1}P$ and you show that $MP^{-1}$ is skew symmetric.
